# How to avoid pie chart external labels overlapping using dc.js

Tags: dc.js

```
   .width(400)
  .height(200)
  .externalLabels(20)
  .externalRadiusPadding(5)
  .drawPaths(true)
  .dimension(genderDimension)
```

This is my code but the external labels are overlapping where there is a narrow slice in piechart.
Is there any why to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag when asking about the JavaScript charting library. [dc] is a venerable old Unix desktop calculator utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only built-in way to deal with this is to use [pieChart.minAngleForLabel](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.pieChart.html#minAngleForLabel__anchor):

> Get or set the minimal slice angle for label rendering. Any slice with a smaller angle will not display a slice label.

It just drops the labels for the narrow slices. The angle is specified in radians.

Currently there is no attempt to avoid collisions between labels. One could imagine bending the lines on the external labels, or making them longer or shorter, but I don't know what algorithm you would use to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to bend  the lines on external labels using dc.js?

Comment: Like I said, there’s nothing like that built in. You could perhaps install an event handler that modifies the lines & label positions but I don’t know how to place them instead.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your reply

Comment: "No attempt" for such a fundamental feature is a really bad news. Come on! Excel can do that, and we can't? I'm working on a solution for this problem - perhaps I'll have something soon.

Comment: Contributions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I actually had some data with a couple of narrow slices, and 2, sometimes 3 labels overlapping. At first I thought this: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9572040 may be a solution, but after playing with it for a moment it turned out is still leads to overlapping labels: when the narrow categories happen to be at the top or bottom of the pie.

I took that solution and modified it:

1. Adopted it to work with dc.js PieChart,
2. Added a recalculation step that ensured the labels do not overlap.

This is not a perfect nor elegant solution. In extreme cases it can make the lines cross one another. It works for me for now, though.

Here's the recalculating function:

```
function recalcLabels(chart) {
    var centroids    = []; 
    var labelYsLeft  = [];
    var labelYsRight = [];
    var radius = chart.radius()*1.25;
    
    // Internal recalculating function
    function adjustLabel(xy, offset=15) {
        var x = xy[0];
        var y = xy[1];

        if (x>0) { // right side
            if (labelYsRight.find(elem => ((y+offset)>elem && ((y-offset)<elem)))) {
                if (y>0) { // Bottom
                    x = x * Math.abs((y-offset)/y);
                    [x,y] = adjustLabel([x, y-offset-2], offset);
                }
                if (y<0) { // Top
                    x = x * Math.abs((y+offset)/y);
                    [x,y] = adjustLabel([x, y+offset+2], offset);
                } 
            }
            labelYsRight.push(y);
        } else { // Left side
            if (labelYsLeft.find(elem => ((y+offset)>elem && ((y-offset)<elem)))) {
                if (y>0) { // Bottom
                    x = x * Math.abs((y-offset)/y);
                    [x,y] = adjustLabel([x, y-offset-2], offset);
                }
                if (y<0) { // Top
                    x = x * Math.abs((y+offset)/y);
                    [x,y] = adjustLabel([x, y+offset+2], offset);
                } 
            }
            labelYsLeft.push(y);
        }
        return [x,y];
    }

    var pie = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){ return d.value; });
    var chartData = pie(chart.data());
    var arc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius*0.5)
        .outerRadius(radius*0.8);
    var outerArc = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius*0.9)
        .outerRadius(radius*0.9) 

    chartData.forEach(function(d, i){
        var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
        var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
        var posC = [...posB];
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
        posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
        var temp = [posA, posB, posC, midangle, d.data.key, i];
        if (temp[1][0]<0 && temp[1][1]<0) {
            centroids.unshift(temp);
        } else {
            centroids.push(temp);
        }
    });
    var adjusted = new Array(centroids.length);
    centroids.forEach(function(d) {
        var [posA, posB, posC, midangle, key, i] = d
        posB = adjustLabel(d[1]);
        posC[1] = posB[1];
        adjusted[i] = [posA, posB, posC, midangle, key];
    });
    return [adjusted, chartData];
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
var pc = dc.pieChart("#my-chart").width(someWidth).height(someHeight)
    .ordering(dc.pluck(function(d){ return d.key; }))
    .radius(80)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .colors(someColors)
    .dimension(someDim)
    .group(someGrp);
pc.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    var [centroids, labels] = recalcLabels(chart); 
    chart.svg().select("g").select("g.pie-label-group").selectAll('polyline')
        .data(labels)
        .enter()
        .append('polyline')
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .style("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr('points', function(d, i) {
            if (d.value>0) { return [centroids[i][0], centroids[i][1], centroids[i][2]]; }
        });
    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').transition().duration(chart.transitionDuration())
        .text( function(d,i) { if (d.value>0) { return centroids[i][4]; }} )
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            var pos = centroids[i][2];
            pos[0] = chart.radius() * 1.25 * (centroids[i][3] < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
        })
        .style('text-anchor', function(d,i) {
            return (centroids[i][3] < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end')
        })
});
pc.on('preRedraw', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('polyline').remove();
});
```

Quick explanation. As you see, first thing I call on pretransition is recalculating the label positions. Then the labels and lines are added to the chart manually (not using built-in dc.js functions). I use the preRedraw to remove old lines before drawing new ones on chart update - this breaks the animation: makes the lines "jump" - not as nice as in the bl.ocks example, but it works for me.

Recalculation is done so that labels in the top part of the pie are pushed down if they overlap, and those at the lower part - pushed up. Top-left side of the chart must be recalculated in reversed order, otherwise lines would cross.

It produces charts like this:

[image]

Made with dc.js v4.2.7 and d3.js v6.7.0.